# How can the physical RAM size be determined from kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

There is function *memblock_phys_mem_size* at *linux/memblock.h* header, but it doesn't exported from kernel so it can't be used in module.

Is there another way to identify RAM size?

Comment: This function marked as `__init` in addition so event if you try to use it you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following symbols:

```
 $ grep EXPORT_SYMBOL mm/*.c | grep total
 mm/highmem.c:EXPORT_SYMBOL(totalhigh_pages);
 mm/page_alloc.c:EXPORT_SYMBOL(totalram_pages);
```

Comment: Thanks you for answer.
It helps me to find symbol 'num_physpages' which satisfy requirement